# Maintaining session on external website using Canvas App

Tags: oauth

We are using OAuth web server flow. We need to know what is the best practice for maintaining session state within the external website. We do not want to use client side coding.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the [OAuth Web Server flow](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&language=en_US) then requesting the [refresh token](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&language=en_US) is the best option to re-establish the session if it expires or is otherwise invalidated.

Being a canvas app, the session should remain valid for the majority of uses. Is the user likely to leave the browser open for an extended period of time? The Salesforce window will close with the expired session, so you won't be able to see the canvas app anymore anyway.

Comment: The refresh flow is being used, and seems to work. However, the website in canvas app can have hyperlinks, and even though the Salesforce session may be logged out, new windows and tabs that are open from these hyperlinks within the canvas app retain valid tokens and oauth server continues to validate the refresh request. What can be done to resolve this?

Comment: @Sara So you want to know when the original Salesforce Session that started the Canvas app expired? Couldn't you just watch for changes in the Session Id that is being used?

Comment: I am not sure about that. Can you please explain it little more? Yes my question is what with those hyperlinks that I have opened and still retain valid token, those should also have been expired, don't they ?

Comment: @Sara I'm a bit confused about what the outstanding questions are? Could you give an example of what the user is experiencing based on changes in the session state?